# Pandasql on Raspbian?

Tags: python, apt, pip

Has anyone successfully installed the Python `pandasql` package on their Raspberry Pi?

```
sudo apt-get install pandasql
```

Gives the following results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pandasql
```

(I can install some version of it using `pip` but it doesn't appear to be compatible with my other packages and my program crashes.)

Comment: You tagged your q with `pip` and that's what you need to use `sudo pip install pandasql` (use pip3 for Python 3)

Comment: @Dirk that does sound like an answer. Please don't use comments to provide answers, preferable post it as an answer instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **apt** instead of **apt-get** you will find information about the repository easier:

```
rpi ~$ apt list *panda*
Listing... Done
perl6-panda/stable 2016.02-1 all
python-geopandas-doc/stable 0.4.0-3 all
python-geopandas/stable 0.4.0-3 all
python-pandas-doc/stable 0.23.3+dfsg-3 all
python-pandas-lib/stable 0.23.3+dfsg-3 armhf
python-pandas/stable 0.23.3+dfsg-3 all
python-sklearn-pandas/stable 1.5.0-1 all
python3-geopandas/stable 0.4.0-3 all
python3-pandas-lib/stable 0.23.3+dfsg-3 armhf
python3-pandas/stable 0.23.3+dfsg-3 all
python3-sklearn-pandas/stable 1.5.0-1 all
x-loader-omap4-panda/stable 1.5.1+git20110715+fca7cd2-2 armhf
```

And **apt** shows you:

```
rpi ~$ apt show python3-pandas
Package: python3-pandas
Version: 0.23.3+dfsg-3
Priority: optional
Section: python
Source: pandas
Maintainer: Debian Science Team <debian-science-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
--- snip ---
Description: data structures for "relational" or "labeled" data - Python 3
 pandas is a Python package providing fast, flexible, and expressive
 data structures designed to make working with "relational" or
 "labeled" data both easy and intuitive.
--- snip ---
```

Is it this you are looking for?